# Spring ConfigurationProperties to work with fluent setters or custom setters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

We are using project lombok for setters and getters and we prefer fluent accessors for setter & getters . The problem arises when we use ConfigurationProperties with fluent accessors. Spring is not able to wire the properties with the class fields . The same things works when we remove the Accessor annotation and have the classic setters and getters. Is there a way we can use custom setters with Configurationproperties

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.experimental.Accessors;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

@ConfigurationProperties
@Data
@Accessors(fluent = true)
public class Properties {

     private String property1;

     private String property2;

}
```

We get a null pointer exception while accessing this property as

```
properties.property1()
```

Comment: Spring uses the Java Bean specification to identify properties. Those are hardwired into the JDK support classes (introspection and reflection). So at the moment spring (boot) doesn't support custom getters and setters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Spring (and thus Spring Boot) uses the [Java Beans Specification](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/spec-136004.html) and for this it uses the default JDK support available.

The introspection and reflection API defines properties as a getter/setter. Setters are `void` and getters should return the actual field (the return and method argument types must also match).

So with that in mind Spring doesn't support custom getters/setters, simply because the JDK classes don't provide this.

Comment: Yeah, the solution would be having Lombok to generate both standard getters/setters and fluent setters (without the "set" prefix).  This feature has been requested multiple times on GitHub but the issues are still open ([#1595](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/1595), [#2141](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/2141) and [#3265](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/3265)).

Answer (score 2):

The framework works with the by convention naming as get***/is***  for getters and set*** for setters.
In addition, @Accessors lombok feature is still **experimental**. Please see this [link](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Accessors)

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Does that mean spring is hard wired to use traditional setter like public void set(Foo foo){...}  , right ?