# Elasticsearch returns empty json-objects

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data, logstash

I'm just getting started with elasticsearch with spring which is both technologies which are completely new to me. I have uploaded data to an elasticseach index with logstash and I can search it successfully using kebana. However when I try to return from an index to a webpage using spring it only returns empty json-objects, but the right amount of empty objects. Did I upload the data incorrectly or is something wrong with my code? I don't understand why this is happening and would appreciate any help I can get. You can find some code below.

Code for type:

```
@Document(indexName="usmgbg_index", type="usmgbg_type")
public class Usmgbg {

    @Id
    private String ID;
    private String Source, Name, Profession, Country, FileName, LastModified, OwnerID;
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository 
public interface UsmgbgRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Usmgbg, String>{}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class UsmgbgController {
    @Autowired
    private UsmgbgRepository repository;
    
    @GetMapping("usmgbg/findall")
    public List<Usmgbg> findAllCustomers() {

        List<Usmgbg> items = new ArrayList<>();
        repository.findAll().forEach(items::add);
      
        return items;
    } 
}
```

The output I'm getting from findAllCustomers looks like:

```
[{},{},{},{},....]
```

Comment: maybe your _source is false?

Comment: Is that an option for the config file, beacuse I'm not using any field called _source, is the default option of _source false?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57308752/spring-configurationproperties-to-work-with-fluent-setters-or-custom-setters

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is an old question but I had the same issue (maybe for a different reason) and I solved it by adding getters and setters in the model.

Answer (score 1):

Iterable is returned from findAll().

If you want to get list you should get content first.

Change

```
@Repository 
public interface UsmgbgRepository extends 
ElasticsearchRepository<Usmgbg, String>{
     Page<Usmgbg> findAll();
}
```

And then

```
repository.findAll().getContent().forEach(items::add);
```

Or fix your code to iterate over the results.

Another solution is to use **search** method in ElasticsearchRepository using QueryBuilders API.

```
  Iterable<Usmgbg>=
  repository.search(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery);
```

Comment: I tried this and it gave the same result. I guess i also  can mention if i print the returning list it looks like this: [com.example.demo.usmgbg.Usmgbg@5025389, com.example.demo.usmgbg.Usmgbg@13dc7f1.....] Thank you!

Comment: I have tried both of your sugenstions but they give the same result? Do you have any other idea?

Comment: No, I don't get any other result when changing the type of client, I will have to look more at it tomorrow! But thanks for the help!

Comment: You can always switch to Java High Level Rest Client https://medium.com/@sourav.pati09/how-to-use-java-high-level-rest-client-with-spring-boot-to-talk-to-aws-elasticsearch-2b6106f2e2c

Answer (score 0):

Adding my experience

`spring-data` requires getters to follow the POJO naming, i.e: `getSomething()`

so it did **not work** (spring-data did not send any fields to ElasticSearch when saving the `@Document`, resulting in an empty `_source` in ES) when having **Lombok** `@Accessors(fluent = true)`, as it removes the `get` prefix on getters ...